# MongoDB - Use iterator_to_array for a single field (PHP)

Tags: php, mongodb

There is a lot being said about to avoid using `iterator_to_array`, so instead we should directly use a `foreach loop` to get the fields returned.

The main reason is that the iterator_to_array loads all the returned documents in the RAM.

But, that is it, and I ask:

What's if the stuff just return only `ONE document`, and that document returns just `ONE field`? 
Isn't iterator_to_array more suited than throwing an loop for it?

And most in case I am using `projections` so that it return just the fields that I'll definetly be passsing into a variable. So naturally it'll be stored in the RAM anyway... '-'

Comment: It sounds like you've answered your own question. :)

Answer (score 0):

There's no harm in using `iterator_to_array()` if your `foreach` loop was just going to collect the documents in an array. As you mentioned, `foreach` has its advantages if you were going to process documents in the result one at a time and didn't need them to co-exist in memory.

If your query is only returning a single document, you might as well use [MongoCollection::findOne()](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.findone.php) and avoid iterating on the MongoCursor yourself.